# How to swap comma for a full stop in JS?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, pixel, price

JS is not my forte but there's something that needs done. The GTM code below is FB-related and takes price from the website. Problem is, the prices use a comma and they need a full stop.

How to adjust the code below so it swaps one for another?

```
<script>
  requirejs(['jquery'], function( jQuery ) {
    jQuery(".c-btn--pdp").click(function() {
       if(jQuery(".c-product-size__selected-option").text() != ""){
            var sku = jQuery(".product-info-stock-sku").find(".value").text();
            var price = jQuery("[data-price-type='finalPrice']").find(".price").text().substring(2);

            console.log("Added Product SKU: " + sku);
            console.log("Added Product Price: " + price);

            fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
            content_ids: sku,
            content_type: 'product',
            value: price,
            currency: {{Currency}}
            });
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: can you add example price

Comment: `yourValue.replace(',', '.')`?

Comment: What is a full stop? Do you mean a period "."? If you want to replace something in a string you can use [String.replace](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-string-replace/): `price = price.replace(",", ".");`

Comment: @DimitriL. "FULL STOP" is the proper name for the character Americans often call a period.  https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+002E

Answer (score 0):

You can use split and join

```
  Query(".c-product-size__selected-option").text() != "") {
  var sku = jQuery(".product-info-stock-sku").find(".value").text();
  var price = jQuery("[data-price-type='finalPrice']").find(".price").text().substring(2);
  price = price.split(',').join('.')
  console.log("Added Product SKU: " + sku);
  console.log("Added Product Price: " + price);
```

Comment: In what part of my code should I add it?

Comment: Check the edits

Answer (score 0):

Use replace:

```
value = price.replace(/,/g,'.')
```

```js
 let price = "12,300"
 console.log(price.replace(/,/g,'.'))
```

Comment: I think this should work

Comment: In what part of my code should I add it?

Comment: You can add it as soon as you query the price

Comment: If you want it use it at a specific place like setting the value you can directly do value = price.replace(/,/g,'.')

Comment: Performance wise regex is slower than split and join

Answer (score 0):

You have to ways:

> str.split(search).join(replacement)
>
> str.replace(/search/g, "replacement");

Using /g with the string will replace all the strings.